# Find Birthday in upcoming month

Tags: sql

I Need help in finding upcoming birthday in a month. 
My Data is something like below , Both data types are nvarchar

[image]
Could anyone help me with the  sql query please?   how to set the DOB column into a date format and then find the birthday with month as 11 and date as 24.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You question is not clear. Give example of data, expected output and programming language to be used.

Comment: It seems you're saying that your `DOB` attribute is text, not a date field. If so, it really shouldn't be.

Comment: Upvote out of date manipulation empathy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, you can use `month()` to extract the month from a date, for example `getdate()`, which is the current point in time. With `left()` you can extract the first characters of a string. That leads to something like:

```
SELECT [Name],
       [Dob(mmdd)]
       FROM elbat
       WHERE month(getdate()) = left([Dob(mmdd)], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can Create a date using the `DATEFROMPARTS(int year, int month, int day)` function. To get your month and day you would have to get the 2 parts of the string, the first 2 characters for month and the third and fourth characters as the day, you can use the `SUBSTRING` function for this. Then take each pair of characters for month and day and cast to int and use them in the `DATEFROMPARTS` function.

Then you want to see if your newly created date is `BETWEEN` today `AND` one month from today. So you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), CAST(SUBSTRING([Dob(mmdd)], 1, 2) as INT), CAST(SUBSTRING([Dob(mmdd)], 3, 2) as INT))
    BETWEEN
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
```

Note: this assumes `[Dob(mmdd)]` is always 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the DOB in a date format.  I am unclear what "upcoming" month means, but I suspect that it means a calendar month.  If the current month, then:

```
where month(getdate()) = cast(left(dob, 2) as int)
```

If the next month, then:

```
where month(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) = cast(left(dob, 2) as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Everyone for the help.. I got this working,. both works perfect

select [USER_ID],[EMP_FULL_NM],[Birthday_Date] from [dbo].[COE]
where month(getdate())=left([Birthday_Date],2)

select [USER_ID],[JOINING_DT],[EMP_FULL_NM] from [dbo].[COE]
   where SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [JOINING_DT], 101),1,2) = month(getdate())